# What is the difference between Kernel density estimation and Parzen window estimation?

Tags: kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

I was reading about non-parametric density estimation when I found out about Kernel Density Estimation (KDE) and Parzen window estimation. Although the text book states both are the same, the equation form seems to be different:

**For Kernel density estimation (KDE) 3D data**

[image]

**For Parzen-window estimation in 3D data**

[image]

Can any one help with this?

Comment: I think these terms are used interchangeably (depending on discipline). The two equations are clearly the same. Here, $K(x)$ is your kernel function in 3 dimensional space. The $k$ function will typically be a PDF.

Comment: @Luca, but 1/h^3 is outside kernel function in KDE, which will be multiplied once, but in case of parzen-window it is inside. isn't that mean in parzen-window kernel function being multiplied by some fraction (1/h^3) each iteration?

Comment: You can take $1/h^3$ outside the summation. It is a constant.

Comment: Multiplying each term in a summation by some fraction is the same as multiplying the sum of terms by that fraction.  $\frac {1}{2} \times 2 + \frac{1}{2} \times 4= \frac{1}{2}\times (2+ 4)$.